# thrust set difference fails to compile with calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed

Tags: compiler-errors, cuda, set, thrust

I have a two sets A & B of 20 & 10 integers respectively. B is a subset of A. I need to find the complimentary set of B. I use thrust::set_difference to find the set difference, However it fails to compile with message: `warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed`

My code is as below. I dont know why this simple code fails to compile.

```
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/set_operations.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>


        thrust::device_vector<int> find_complimentary_set(thrust::device_vector<int> A, thrust::device_vector<int> B)
        {

        thrust::sort(thrust::device, A.begin(), A.end());
        thrust::sort(thrust::device, B.begin(), B.end());

        int N=A.size()-B.size();
        thrust::device_vector<int> complimentary_set(N);

        **// the following line causes the compilation error**
        thrust::set_difference(thrust::device, A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end(), complimentary_set);

        return complimentary_set;

        }
            int main(int argc, char * argv[])
            {
            int N=20;
            thrust::device_vector<int> A(N);
            thrust::sequence(thrust::device, A.begin(), A.end(),0); 

            thrust::device_vector<int> B(10);
            B[0]=2;B[1]=4;B[2]=8;B[3]=10;B[4]=11;B[5]=13;B[6]=15;B[7]=17;B[8]=19;B[9]=6;

            find_complimentary_set(A, B);

            return 0;
            }
```

My compilation error is huge. I found the 8 errors in them which i list below:

```
    /usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/detail/set_operation.inl(517): error: no operator "+" matches these operands
                operand types are: thrust::device_vector<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int>> + thrust::reference<signed long, thrust::pointer<signed long, thrust::system::cuda::detail::par_t, thrust::use_default, thrust::use_default>, thrust::use_default>

    /usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/detail/set_operation.inl(648): error: no operator "+" matches these operands
                operand types are: thrust::device_vector<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int>> + signed long

/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/detail/sequential/set_operations.h(64): error: no operator "*" matches these operands
            operand types are: * thrust::device_vector<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int>>

/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/detail/sequential/set_operations.h(66): error: no operator "++" matches these operands
            operand types are: ++ thrust::device_vector<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int>>

/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/iterator/iterator_traits.h(49): error: class "thrust::device_vector<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int>>" has no member "iterator_category"

/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/detail/sequential/general_copy.h(106): error: no operator "++" matches these operands
            operand types are: ++ thrust::device_vector<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int>>

/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/detail/sequential/general_copy.h(76): error: no operator "*" matches these operands
            operand types are: * thrust::device_vector<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int>>
```

Comment: That is a warning, not an error, and won"t stop compilation. The compilation error, which you have not showed will be related to the last argument, which is incorrect

Comment: added error messages. found the error. added the answer. thanks

Comment: isn't this the exact same mistake as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/53475531/681865 ?

Comment: oops. good find. I am newbie in cuda & thrust with a lot going on everyday. I forgot that the problem had already been solved before.

Answer (score 1):

While using thrust::set_difference the arguments are iterators and not the device_vectors. the last argument to the set_difference has to be complimentary_set.begin() instead of complimentary_set.

the entire correct statement now reads:

```
thrust::set_difference(thrust::device, A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end(), complimentary_set.begin());
```